# Why doesn't Plotly (in Python3) make different lines in a linechart?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to build a linechart with Plotly for Python3. My chart shows the number of UFO sightings in 5 states over time. However, all the points are connected with one line instead of one line for each of the 5 states. How can I get plotly to recognize that the data has different states? I feel like I do this with the "text" argument but that did not work.

##### Data

```
    year    state   sightings
7   1930    NY         2    
10  1931    NY         1    
13  1933    NY         1    
16  1935    CA         2    
20  1937    CA         1
```

##### Code

```py
import plotly.express as px # plotly library

fig = px.line(state_UFO_sightings, 
              x="year", 
              y="total", 
              text="sightings",
              title = "Top 5 states with most UFO sightings")
fig.show()
```

##### Current line graph

[image]

Comment: Try keyword argument `color` instead of `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> color="state"

in your plot function.

Answer (score 0):

- data set is on kaggle.  Have used this.
- simple case of three parameters to `px.line()`
- key is `color` parameter.  Your graph can be explained by fact you are mixing states in single trace

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

# download some images to demonstrate
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/NUFORC/ufo-sightings"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()

zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f), on_bad_lines="skip", low_memory=False)for f in zfile.infolist()}

df = dfs["complete.csv"]
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"], errors="coerce")

# calculate sightings
df = (
    df.loc[df["country"].eq("us")]
    .groupby([df["datetime"].dt.year, "state"], as_index=False)
    .size()
    .rename(columns={"datetime": "year", "size": "sightings"})
)

# top 5 states over all time
df = df.loc[
    df["state"].isin(
        df.groupby("state")
        .agg({"sightings": "sum"})
        .sort_values("sightings", ascending=0)
        .head(5)
        .index
    )
]

px.line(df, x="year", y="sightings", color="state")
```

[image]